# Remove localStorage from Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to develop a simple Chrome Extension with the aim to manipulate localStorage - get, remove and change. I am following this documentation about [Chrome storage](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/storage):

> "It provides the same storage capabilities as the localStorage API"

I am placing my code in popup.html in the format like this:

```
var name = 'key of the localstorage object';
chrome.storage.sync.remove(name, function(response) {
  alert(response);
});
```

I can see the 'name' variable as a key in the Application - localStorage when I inspect elements and I can remove it by `localStorage.removeItem(name)` in the console. But when I click to the extension icon and the popup run with popup.js, it won't remove the key using the above syntax.

My manifest json permission:

```
"permissions": ["activeTab", "cookies", "storage", "webNavigation", "tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
```

I can easily manipulate cookies from the same popup and everything works fine, just can't figure out why I can't manipulate the localStorage.

Comment: `chrome.storage` is different from `localStorage`. You cannot access/modify one of them with the other's methods.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the edit and explanation. So the only way to change localstorage in popup is via contentScript?

Comment: Which `localStorage` do you want to change? A webpage's one or your extension's popup one? In the former case, use a content script. In the latter, directly using `localStorage` in your code.